# HtmlUnit & GWT error

Tags: gwt, htmlunit, firefox3.6

I've a GWT application that I try to index.

I am using HtmlUnit to get the content of the generated HTML:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
HtmlPage refDesing = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080/MyGWTApp/#page2");
FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("D:\\work\\out\\page2.html");
fos1.write(refDesing.asXml().getBytes());
fos1.close();
```

But I get the following error and the page returned approximately empty!

```
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:25 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx.nocache.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [485:24] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [485:29] Error in style rule. Invalid token "\n". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [485:29] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [518:24] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [518:29] Error in style rule. Invalid token "\n  ". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [518:29] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [541:24] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [541:29] Error in style rule. Invalid token "\n  ". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [541:29] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [951:24] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [951:29] Error in style rule. Invalid token "\n". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [951:29] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [977:24] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [977:29] Error in style rule. Invalid token "\n". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
Dec 22, 2010 6:16:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [977:29] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
```

**EDIT:**

What I mean by approximately empty is, here's snapshot of the returned HTML:

Please note that, not all data that is displayed in the original page (which original got from DB) is returned by HtmlUnit. Also What "?" means? I don't think it means any encoding error cause all words are clear ASCII characters.

```
<td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <table class="refDesignGrid" cellspacing="5">
      <colgroup>
        <col/>
      </colgroup>
      <tbody align="left">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <table cellpadding="0" class="categoryItem" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div class="header4">
                      C++
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <table cellpadding="0" class="categoryItem" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div class="header4">
                      Java
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td align="left">
            <table cellpadding="0" class="categoryItem" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div class="header4">
                      C#
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
          <td>
            ?
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here:
http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork

> The main thread using HtmlUnit may be finishing execution before
>   allowing background threads to run. You have a couple of options:
>
> webClient.setAjaxController(new
>   NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()); will tell your WebClient
>   instance to re-synchronize asynchronous XHR.
>   webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000); or
>   webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000); just after
>   getting the page and before manipulating it. Explicitly wait for a
>   condition that is expected be fulfilled when your JavaScript runs,
>   e.g.
>
> ```
> //try 20 times to wait .5 second each for filling the page.
> for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
>     if (condition_to_happen_after_js_execution) {
>          break;
>      }
>      synchronized (page) {
>          page.wait(500);
>      }
> }
> ```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

HtmlUnit can be kinda chatty, and in particular can make things look worse than they are.

Create these two classes:

```
import org.w3c.css.sac.CSSException;
import org.w3c.css.sac.CSSParseException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler;

/*
 * get rid of warnings... and provide a place to hang a break point
 */
public class QuietCssErrorHandler
    extends DefaultCssErrorHandler
{

    @Override public void error( CSSParseException e ) throws CSSException 
    {
        super.error( e ) ;
    }

    @Override public void fatalError( CSSParseException e ) throws CSSException 
    { 
        super.fatalError( e ) ; 
    }

    @Override public void warning( CSSParseException e ) throws CSSException 
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListener;

public class SilentIncorrectnessListener
    implements IncorrectnessListener
{
    @Override public void notify( String message, Object origin ) 
    {
        // do nuttin' honey!
    }
}
```

then when you create your WebClient...

```
wc.setIncorrectnessListener( new SilentIncorrectnessListener() ) ;
wc.setCssErrorHandler( new QuietCssErrorHandler() ) ;
```

And you should then get fewer warnings.

As for "approximately empty"... what does that mean?

Comment: These handlers show me the same errors when registered to the WebClient instance. Please see my edit about "approximately empty"